# How to automatically save virtualbox vm state before logout?

Tags: virtualbox, script, logout

I'm using oneiric with unity. I want to find a solution to automatically save the state of my virtualbox virtual machine before I logout or shutdown because I always forget to do it manually. I know I can use `Vboxmanage controlvm [vmname] savestate` to save state in terminal. But how do I make ubuntu execute this command before logging out?

Comment: This is not so much about VirtualBox, as it is about running scripts automatically in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Vboxmanage command to your ~/.bash_logout file and it will execute upon the logoff event.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/91829/save-virtualbox-vm-state-before-logout